# Django declaring a read-only field on serializer

Tags: django, primary-key, django-serializer

I have an endpoint that needs to expose the fields to the user, but under a different name. The user should -not- be able to set the PK (called `orderId` here) when creating the object, since that should be done automatically with a randomly set value when the object is created.

Here is my serializer.

```
class OrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    orderId = serializers.UUIDField(source="id")
    orderName = serializers.CharField(source="name")

    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = (
            "orderId",
            "orderName",
        )
        read_only_fields = ("orderId",)
```

Here is my model:

```
class Order(models.Model):

    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=48)
```

Note that `id` in the model is exposed to the user under the name `orderId`.

The problem is this set up seems to make it a required field when when a user creates an order. With the above set up, a POST request setting just `orderName` in the body to create an order gives this error:

```
{
    "orderId": [
        "This field is required."
    ]
}
```

Unless of course the user sends a value for `orderId`, which they should not do.

I had hoped including the "orderId" as a ready only field would make it not required in a POST request, but that does not seem to be the case. Obviously the field needs to be required in the DB, but it should not be required in a POST request.

If I remove the `orderId` from fields, I get:

```
The field 'messageId' was declared on serializer OrderSerializer, but has not been included in the 'fields' option.
```

And if I remove if from the serialize entirely (remove `orderId = serializers.UUIDField(source="id")`) then I can create an Order but the id does not show up in a GET request, where I need it to be seen.

How can I make it so that the order's primary key `id` is...

- visible to the user in a GET request
- visible to the user under the name `orderId`
- not a required field when generating an order, since it should be automatically created like most Primary Keys are

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should specify `read_only=True` to mark the field as readonly. By customizing it yourself, you prevented Django from doing this itself:

```
class OrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    orderId = serializers.UUIDField(source='id', read_only=True)
    orderName = serializers.CharField(source='name')

    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = (
            'orderId',
            'orderName',
        )
        read_only_fields = ('orderId',)
```

Comment: That did it, thanks! I did not realize it needed to be specified as read-only in when you define it in the serializer and not just in the Meta class as I had it.

Comment: If I may ask a followup: Doing this also seems to have overridden the `help_text` field from my model (I did not include the help_text here for simplicity). I don't want to write the help_text twice (in model an serializer) for all of the fields I do this with, is there a way to grab the help text from the source field instead of defining it explicitly again?